# How to show correct local string in VS Code Terminal or any Terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, internationalization

Recently I'm working with [NodeJS Intl Object](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html) , I written my codes in VS code and run the code with NodeJS version 12 but I can't see expected output. my codes are :

```
const number = (12000).toLocaleString("ar-EG");
console.log(number);
```

when I run this code it's print **12,000** but I expect it should print **١٢٬٠٠٠** , also when I run my codes in Chrome web browser everything works fine but not in Terminal or VS Code Terminal . so what configuration must be set to see the correct output ? 
my OS is Linux Mint

Answer (score 1):

Because VSC terminal not supporting Arabic numbers, to test it try to write the output in file and open it by any app support Arabic numbers

Please check this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales)